# How to produce just the intercept using model.matrix?

Tags: r, regression, formula

The function `stats::model.matrix` can be used to convert an input data frame into a matrix suitable for raw algebraic manipulation in solving regression equations etc. For example:

```
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(5), n = rnorm(5))
model.matrix(~., data = df)
```

produces:

```
  (Intercept)          a            n
1           1  1.2629543 -1.539950042
2           1 -0.3262334 -0.928567035
3           1  1.3297993 -0.294720447
4           1  1.2724293 -0.005767173
5           1  0.4146414  2.404653389
```

One of the features is that it controls how the intercept is added to the design matrix. Compare: `model.matrix(~ 0 + ., data = df)` vs `model.matrix(~ 1 + ., data = df)`

Now, the `.` in the formula specifies that all variables of `df` should be included. This leads to a problem when I wish to pass an empty data frame and thus create just the intercepts, e.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(, nrow=5, ncol=0))
model.matrix(~  ., data = df)
```

leads to:

```
Error in terms.formula(object, data = data) : 
  '.' in formula and no 'data' argument
```

Does anyone know how to get around this, to be specific, I want to produce the following result given by `model.matrix(~  1, data = df)`, except using the `.`.

Comment: How about `if (ncol(df) == 0) model.matrix(~  1, data = df) else model.matrix(~  ., data = df)`

Comment: that is helpful and is currently what i am doing, however are there more direct ways of passing some object to model.matrix without the if statements.

Comment: May I ask why would you pass an empty data.frame?.  It is strange to make a formula out of nothing. At most You can have 1 column data.frame with 1s instead. Consider this `model.matrix(~1,data=data.frame(rep(1,10)))`

Comment: I have a custom class of regressions that accepts a data frame or matrix as inputs for the covariates. I would like to compute the null model to serve as a baseline, for this it makes sense to be able to pass some 'null' data frame object which triggers regression against a constant. As suggested by @Gregor I could have an if statement inside my function to detect the difference, however, it is my opinion that this should be handled at the level of `model.matrix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
model.matrix(as.formula(paste0("~", colnames(df), "+1", collapse="+")), data=df)
```

However, I think you are better off using an if statement.  I think formulas in R are more convenience than anything fundamental.

Comment: I like your idea of programmatically generating the formula from text. Can you justify why you think I am better off using an if statement?

Comment: The intent of the `if` statement is crystal clear. If someone else reads the code (or maybe even you in a couple years) and sees the `if` statement, its purpose is clear and they could probably guess why `model.matrix(~ .)` isn't used (the 0-column input is a special case). With this formula, someone who knows R but isn't aware of this weird edge would probably think "this formula should just be `~ .`" and maybe even change it, creating a bug.

Comment: I agree with Gregor, I think it's a little bit clearer to use if statement.  To use a character string and convert, it's basically 4 nested function calls.

Comment: Also, it seems like your project is of limited scope now, but perhaps at some point you want users to be able to pass in a `formula` argument - maybe `~ .` is a good default but somebody wants to make the code do `~ .^2` or specify a custom formula. The `if` statement doesn't bat an eye, you just change the `else` to the `formula` argument and it extends easily. The paste column names method, not so much.

Comment: Thanks, those are all very good points, especially with regards to interactions and stuff.